# Unity 3d Editor's inspector shows "failed to load"

Tags: unity-game-engine

Mac OS X 10.10.3

Unity 4.6.3f1

Each time I Create a New Untiy Project, the inspector show "Failed to load"(See below)

Why? How to deal with it?

[image]

Comment: have you been tried to open inspector tab again from windows???

Answer (score 1):

That is because your previous project had custom tools in the project folder.

When you load this project, it trys to keep your previous window layout.

Because this is a new project, there is no tool scripts to be found.

Just close the tab or add the tools back into your project.

Answer (score -2):

could also happen when file and class name got slight

diferent spelling :

http://prismbucket.com/unity-editor-window-issues